# Is there a way to override getString() for resources the android framework inflates?

Tags: android

Is there any way to intercept the Android framework's inflation of xml resources (menus and layouts) to change the strings it uses (e.g. for attributes like `android:text="@string/button_trade_commit"`.)

I know it's possible to override `getString()` as it's called from an Activity.  But framework code doesn't seem to use `getString()`.  For example, in MenuInflator.java, strings come from `mContext.obtainStyledAttributes()`, and `obtainStyledAttributes()` is final: I can't override it.

Anybody know of another way to accomplish this?

Background: I want to allow non-English-speaking users to localize my app themselves. I imagine an interface that displays the English strings and lets them enter a translation which is then used in place of the English string from then on. I can imagine also providing a "Share translations" button that uploads the translations, and then,
on the server side, incorporating them into a downloadable module that other users of the same language would get.  Being able to substitute strings at runtime is the blocking piece that I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can override the systems getString() methods the way you are looking at it.
It might be worth trying to use a custom attribute and handle the work there: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr

Comment: This works reasonably well for layout resources: I can just subclass widgets like Button and provide my own strings based on custom attributes. Menus are more problematic because you never have access to an AttributeSet: custom attributes are useless. So what I'm going to try is replacing the title of each menu with a string (rather than a reference), and in onCreateOptionsMenu() use that string as a key into the actual strings (to replace the menuitem's title.) I'll build the key->string mapping at build time from R.java so there should be no additional mapping that needs to be maintained.

Comment: It turns out there are too many inconsistencies in the Android framework to allow a single/generic fix for this.  I tried rewriting my .xml files at build time, replacing @string/string_name with _loc:string_name, then at runtime walking inflated Views and substituting for strings beginning with _loc:. But some resource elements, e.g. Spinner's prompt, MUST be given a reference. This isn't worth doing if it turns the code into spaghetti, but that seems to be the way I'm headed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to modify the process Android uses when inflating resources the way you wanted to.

What you can do is to simply not provide any strings (`android:text`, etc.) in XML files. You can always obtain a reference to any element in your XML file in the code. Once you have a reference, you can provide texts in the code, taking properly localized strings from your custom framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but i think you can examine the source of [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library for Android. It is overriding system LayoutInflater to change the FontType, so i imagine you can do the same to change the strings.